# Renaming a directory with VB.Net in SSIS package

Tags: vb.net, ssis, rename, filesystemobject

I have an issue which I do not fully understand.

```
    Public Sub Main()
    Dim OldBrokerFolder As String
    Dim NewBrokerFolderName As String

    OldBrokerFolder = CType(Dts.Variables("User::strBrokerStatementFolder").Value, String)
    NewBrokerFolderName = CType(Dts.Variables("User::strBrokerStatementNewFolderName").Value, String)

    OldBrokerFolder = OldBrokerFolder.Substring(0, 41)

    MsgBox(OldBrokerFolder)

    FileIO.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(OldBrokerFolder, NewBrokerFolderName)

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

When I comment out the Msgbox I get an error. However, when I leave the Msgbox uncommitted, I have to click a dialogue box, but the folder renames fine.

I don't understand what is going on? I just want to rename the old folder with a new name

Thanks

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Hi Hadi. The error is a standard DTS Script Task: Runtime Error. "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" However, something else worked that I don't understand. If I remove the two package variables feeding into the script task and instead hardcode the script variables OldBrokerFolder and NewBrokerFolderName inside the script itself and, put the script task for renaming the directory in another package and call it from the main package; the rename function works fine. And it's not a mistake or a typo in the path name either. I don't understand the behaviour but it's working